# how to read FAKE JSON response from ticker API of unocoin bitcoin exchange?

Tags: java, json, api

First of all i am sorry if i am wrong that the response is fake JSON ...
the api i am using is ticker api of unocoin
https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all

I have been working on a website which takes the rate from various indian bitcoin exchanges and plot the graphs for easy visualization.So far i have added 3 exchanges and got their rate from their TICKER API,the response i got is just plane text and no other surprises..

all these exchanges like 
ZEBPAY: https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr
Koinex: https://koinex.in/api/ticker
made my life easier but
making a get request to unocoin api gives me a html page with only an iframe in body tag and i am not able to directly(or indirectly) use data in my code.
there is an alternate method to get access to many features but it requires me to register and feed my ACCESS TOKEN in every request which i don't prefer right now.

to make api calls i am using java and code is given belowe:

```
private static String sendGet(String host,String apiEndpoint) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(host+apiEndpoint);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    return(response.toString());
}
```

just a note: i got google recaptcha if i make a lot of request in small time frame

the result from above code is

```
<html><head><META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow"><script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05"></script><script>(function() { var z="";var b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for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();</script></head><body><iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe></body></html>
```

i just want the response just like i get in my browser after visiting 
https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all

Comment: Strangely I'm not even being allowed to visit the site:

www.unocoin.com -
Access Denied
Error code 16
This request was blocked by the security rules

Comment: maybe it's a country restriction or temporarily down, still working for me

Answer (score 0):

The website is protected by an anti-scraping script called [Incapsula](https://www.incapsula.com/) that tries to run a small Javascript bit, but since you are using Java it won't be able to run it, unless you are using `Selenium` or like the `V8` engine, but this is a bit not recommended because you are somehow breaking the rules of what they considered to be intrusive for them, but my recommendation:

Talk with the guys from `unocoin.com` and ask them to whitelist your IP if they are okay with you scraping their site.

Comment: thanks for the response but...
in general aren't api supposed to be accessed by bots and softwares ?
I have used selenium before and i know it's a bit resource hungry so i din't chose to go with it. 

anyways thanks...

Comment: https://www.unocoin.com/apidoc#getting-started. This is their official API. If you call an unofficial api, I presume is because that you are not supposed to call it with a bot. Qn api can be consumed if the one owning the api agrees to make it public, especially unauthenticated. Think if you would start hitting their api 1 million times with parallel bots running? You would probably make their website very slow or even worse, make their site go down, which would be illegal and considered a DDoS. I repeat, send an email ti them and ask them if are okay to be crawled

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the API, you can do it by scraping the Unocoin Ticker API All Rates webpage. This would break if there is some change in the website, but till then it works.

It can be implemented via `WebKit` using `WKWebView`, `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol and then injecting some `JavaScript`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.isHidden = true
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    // For checking if website has loaded
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Injecting JS to fetch HTML inside <body>
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML", completionHandler: {
            (html: Any?, error: Error?) in

            if error == nil && html != nil {
                // Perform string manipulation and parse JSON to get data
            } else {
                // Error while fetching data
            }
        })
    }
}
```